# Change column name based on row values

Tags: r, data.table

For the data tables below, I would like to rename the column fruit if it contains either "apple" or "orange", i.e. I'd like to rename the column fruit within DT but not within DT2.

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(colour = c("green", "red", "red", "red", "blue","red"), fruit = c("apple", "orange", "pear", "apple", "apple","banana"))
DT2 <- data.table(colour = c("green", "red", "red", "red", "blue","red"), fruit = c("pear", "pear", "pear", "banana", "pear","banana"))
```

I want to first search for whether the data table contains the column fruit, so I tried the code below but it renames fruit within DT and within DT2:

```
alist <- list(DT, DT2)
lapply(alist, function(x) {
if ("fruit" %in%  colnames(x)){
x <- x[fruit=="apple"|fruit=="orange", setnames(x, old="fruit", new="appfruit")]
x}})
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `if (any(grepl("apple|orange", DT$fruit))) colnames(DT)[2] <- "appfruit"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing your function to:

```
lapply(alist, function(x) {
  if(any(x[["fruit"]] %in% c("apple","orange"))) {
    setnames(x, old = "fruit", new = "appfruit")
  }}
)
```

will give the intended result (see below for extended example data):

> ```
> > alist
> [[1]]
>    colour appfruit
> 1:  green    apple
> 2:    red   orange
> 3:    red     pear
> 4:    red    apple
> 5:   blue    apple
> 6:    red   banana
>
> [[2]]
>    colour  fruit
> 1:  green   pear
> 2:    red   pear
> 3:    red   pear
> 4:    red banana
> 5:   blue   pear
> 6:    red banana
>
> [[3]]
>    colour veggie
> 1:  green  apple
> 2:    red   pear
> 3:    red   pear
> 4:    red banana
> 5:   blue   pear
> 6:    red banana
> ```

As you can see, when there is no `fruit`-column, the columnname is not changed.

---

Used data:

```
DT1 <- data.table(colour = c("green", "red", "red", "red", "blue","red"), fruit = c("apple", "orange", "pear", "apple", "apple","banana"))
DT2 <- data.table(colour = c("green", "red", "red", "red", "blue","red"), fruit = c("pear", "pear", "pear", "banana", "pear","banana"))
DT3 <- data.table(colour = c("green", "red", "red", "red", "blue","red"), veggie = c("apple", "pear", "pear", "banana", "pear","banana"))

alist <- list(DT1, DT2, DT3)
```